# Autoincrement VersionCode Gradle task not executing as expected

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I wanted to automate android gradle versioning my requirement is

Ver Code  Version Name

[image]

So i have runned code in java application

Code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int fileVersionCode = 1;
    String fileVersionName;
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        if (fileVersionCode <= 10) {
            fileVersionName = "1." + (fileVersionCode - 1);
        } else if(fileVersionCode>=20 && fileVersionCode%10 ==0) {
            fileVersionName = ( (fileVersionCode / 10)) + ".9";
        }else {
            fileVersionName = (1 + (fileVersionCode / 10)) + "." +( (fileVersionCode % 10)-1);
        }
        System.out.println(fileVersionCode+"         "+fileVersionName);
        fileVersionCode++;
    }
}
```

And my code is working as expected but in gradle for the same code

```
task firstTask {
doFirst {
    int fileVersionCode = 1;
    String fileVersionName;
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        if (fileVersionCode <= 10) {
            fileVersionName = "1." + (fileVersionCode - 1);
        } else if(fileVersionCode>=20 && fileVersionCode%10 ==0) {
            fileVersionName = ( (fileVersionCode / 10)) + ".9";
        }else {
            fileVersionName = (1 + (fileVersionCode / 10)) + "." +( (fileVersionCode % 10)-1);
        }
        System.out.println(fileVersionCode+"         "+fileVersionName);
        fileVersionCode++;
    }
}
doLast{
//        println 'firstTask doLast'
}
}
```

Run :> gradlew firstTask

output is different why i am getting like this
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In groovy a division results in a `BigDecimal` if the operands are of type `Integer`, while in Java they are of the type `int`.

When `fileVersionCode` is `11`, the result:

```
(fileVersionCode / 10)
```

translates to `1` in Java but to `1.1` in Groovy. In order to fix this, just add a `(int)` cast to trim the unnecessary decimal part.